# Can I create a unit test at runtime in C# using reflection?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, nunit

I have a scenario where I'm needing to create tests at runtime based on a script.

I have a set of scenarios defined in a text file that need to be interpreted and each one should be run as an unit test under nunit.

I've created a general IntegrationTestRunner to read the data and run one big test for each scenario that is defined. This works fine.

However, it seems to make good sense that each scenario should be it's own unit test.

Is there a way to dynamically create nunit-based unit tests at runtime using reflection?

Thank you!

Comment: Since it's already working with one giant one, couldn't you refactor and create a test POCO with the test name and the result to be used in a more generic method? Could you elaborate on what you mean by "should be it's own unit test"? It sounds like you already have everything you need. Just lacking some grouping.

Comment: I could -- however the expected result may change. Think of this as a poor man's version of SpecFlow for BDD/Integration Tests. With that said -- it wouldn't be appropriate to hard code everything into standard objects (at least, that's the way it looks now.)

Comment: And you don't want to use a [TestCaseSource](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=testCaseSource&r=2.6.3)?

Comment: I had no idea TestCaseSource existed. I think that's what I'm looking for. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It'd be quicker and far easier to create a class that reads all the test cases from your file and creates `TestCaseData` objects (see [this page](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=testCaseSource&r=2.6.3)).  You can set the name of each test case via the `Name` property on the `TestCaseData`.